# nVidia GPU Decode and Encode YUV422

Tags: video, cuda, gpu, decoding

I've created an application to decode(for now) mpeg2 vídeos.

Everything runs well when the video has YUV420 ChromaSampling(IMG1), but when in YUV422(IMG2) I just get a bunch of artifacts (IMG3).

I've search for a while and read posts saying that nVidia does not support 422, but this seams odd. Is there any way to go around this?

[image: IMG1]

[image: IMG2]

[image: IMG3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of anyone else searches for this, here it goes:

I kept digging and I submitted a ticket to nVidia Developer and got this response:

> Yes, it's a known limitation. The 4:2:2 mpeg-2 decode is not supported(Only 4:2:0 mpeg-2 is supported). Sorry for the inconvenience.

So, basically using cuvid YUV 422 ChromaSampling is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

omg, small text is so meaningful https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk
But scheme is about `Ampere` family and not for all GPU

> ** 4:2:2 is not natively supported on HW

And now `Amper` supports more features than any other.
Check your gpu family https://developer.nvidia.com/video-encode-and-decode-gpu-support-matrix-new#Encoder